# Broadcast Realtime SQL data using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signals

Hub file

```
namespace SignalR
{
\[HubName("notificationHub")\]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
\[HubMethodName("sendNotifications")\]

        public object SendNotifications()
    
        {
            var reader = "";
    
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    
            {
    
                string query = "select Name_print from Print_Name_Machine where User_ID = '123'";
    
                connection.Open();
    
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    
                {
    
                    command.Notification = null;
    
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    
    
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
    
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
    
                    }
                    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    reader = dr["Name_print"].ToString();
    
                    connection.Close();
    
                }
    
            }
    
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    
            return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(reader);
    
        }
    
        public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    
            {
    
                SendNotifications();
    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Index file

```
@*@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }*@

<div class="row">
    <h1>Broadcast Realtime SQL data using SignalR</h1>

    <div>

        <p>You have <span id="spanNewMessages">0</span> New Message Notification.</p>

    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.js"></script>

    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.

            var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;

            //debugger;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.

            notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages) {

                // Add the message to the page.

                $('#spanNewMessages').text(totalNewMessages);


            };

            // Start the connection.

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                notifications.server.sendNotifications();

            }).fail(function (e) {

                alert(e);

            });

            //$.connection.hub.start();

        });

    </script>
}
```

Startup.cs file

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalR.Startup))]

namespace SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I want when the data on the database changes to show a message on the index page, but this code only works once when the page loads.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------